# Finally handler when using 'all' aggregation function on an array of promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

I have some code that opens and reads a SQL script file and opens a connection to the database in parallel, when they are done it executes the contents of the file on the connection. However, the connection result needs to be 'closed'. I need to be able to handle the case where the database connection succeeds and reading the file fails (wrong filename perhaps) and still close the connection in either case.

Here is the code I am currently using, it has a `finally()` handler to close the client if the query succeeds or fails, but if the file read fails the client will not be closed.

```
function execFile(db, file) {
    console.log('Connecting to ' + db);
    return Promise.all([
        connect('postgres://' + credentials + host + '/' + db),
        fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
    ]).spread(function(client, initSql) {
        console.log('Connected to ' + db);
        console.log('Running init script ' + file);
        return client.queryAsync(initSql).finally(client.end);
    });
}
```

I played a little with the `bind()` function to pass the client into the finally block but I'm not very happy with the complexity that it introduces. I have a feeling that `settle()` could be useful here and I'm playing with that now.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function execFile(db, file) {
    console.log('Connecting to ' + db);
    var client = connect('postgres://' + credentials + host + '/' + db);
    var initSql = fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8');
    return Promise.all([client, initSql]).spread(function(client, initSql) {
        console.log('Connected to ' + db);
        console.log('Running init script ' + file);
        return client.queryAsync(initSql);
    }).finally(function() {
       if (client.isFulfilled()) client.inspect().value().end();
    });
}
```

Comment: Woah. Cool. I really want that to work. Does it work? I ask because I have a poor understanding of this yet and it looks like it might try to close the connection before the Promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Does `all` complete only after all Promises are fulfilled and/or rejected? I like this; the only change I would make is to check the resolution of the client promise, if it was rejected there would be no need to call `end()`. Also I think `client` and `initSql` in the outer scope should be `clientPromise` and `sqlPromise` respectively, then `clientPromise.value.end()` in the `finally`.

Comment: @Metagrapher the finally is called in a success situation *after* connection is established, file is read and the query has been completed.

Comment: @joshperry agree (but not with the verbose hungarian notation suffix :P), check the edit

Comment: @Esailija Haha, fair enough. Could you elaborate on what `inspect()` is for in this case?

Comment: @joshperry for some reason the promise objects themselves do not have a `.value()` function :P You need to get the [inspection object](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#synchronous-inspection) which has a value function to get the fulfilled value.

Comment: @Esailija Ah interesting, so it is as you say. It makes sense to be able to snapshot something that could be changed asynchronously. Still a little new with the promises, been doing CPS mostly; definitely enjoying Promises more than the pyramid of doom!

Comment: @joshperry actually `.value()` will always return the same value or throw an error because the promise wasn't fulfilled and as such calling `.value()` was an error. I think I will implement .error() and .value() on the promise directly in future. Also, your use case here is a good reason to implement [`Promise.using`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/65).